# Error: app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug

Tags: android, exception, kotlin

I have a class HillfortStore in this package:

```
package org.wit.hillforts.models
```

Messed up the package name in the class (missing the 's'):

```
package org.wit.hillforts.model
```

Imported class into other classes with wrong package name, it works just fine:

```
import org.wit.hillforts.model.HillfortStore
```

To clean things up I fix the name in the class and all classes its imported into. Now I'm getting this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dex archives: setting .DEX extension only for .CLASS files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just do this :

in main project folder ,in terminal type

```
cd android
```

then type this

```
./gradlew clean
```

then build your app again

Comment: You are a hero!

Comment: For ionic apps the "cd android"  become "cd platforms/android". Then it works !

Comment: @Sajad Saderi can you help me with this please.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to complete a rebuild of the app.
This is all it took to fix the issue.
It is working now.

Answer (score 3):

Delete .gradle file from your project folder then clean the project and Rebuild

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem because Lombok plugin didn't work with new gradle. Just removed these lines:

> ```
> compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
> annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
> ```

and the problem disappeared.

Maybe you also have some kind of "troubled" plugin that doesn't get along with new gradle)

Answer (score 0):

run this in npm
$cd android

than run
$gradlew clean

than run
$cd ..

and finally, run
$npx react-native run-android