# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'. :can't build my app

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-multidex

This is the error log :

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\User\lenovo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ea4133cb13233edf48fd09c8aeaa2352\jars\classes.jar
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
>       at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:420)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$4.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:338)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:312)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:158)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:28)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:133)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$5(CacheStep.java:83)
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:88)
>       at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
>       at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
>       at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>       at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
>       at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
>       at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\User\lenovo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ea4133cb13233edf48fd09c8aeaa2352\jars\classes.jar
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:834)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
>       at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
>       at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
>       at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
>       ... 7 more
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Interface `com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcv(classpath class)` used as super class of `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Param`.
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
>       ... 10 more
>
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\User\lenovo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ea4133cb13233edf48fd09c8aeaa2352\jars\classes.jar

Edit : build.gradle file

```
    import com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.veblr.videomate"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 16
    versionName "1.0.0.8"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = true
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    resConfigs "en"
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        jniDebuggable true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        ///shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'

        //Other parameters
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        pseudoLocalesEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled true

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
ext {
    roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.0'
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/XXX'
    exclude 'META-INF/license/LICENSE.base64.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "12g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
 }
afterEvaluate {
tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
}.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
    } else {
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    }
    }


   }
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'

}
     maven{  url  "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony"}
     maven {  url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
     }
    }
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.2.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector- 
impl:17.0.5"

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.27.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.27.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'


//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

implementation 'org.piwik.sdk:piwik-sdk:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'

// Room components
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
// Lifecycle components
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-rc02'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Try [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996612/error-apptransformclasseswithdexbuilderfordebug) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996612/error-apptransformclasseswithdexbuilderfordebug)

Comment: @Basi  it's not working on the given solution

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file ?

Comment: @Amine i posted the build.gradle file

Comment: try put this statement `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig.

Comment: @amine already there. I also removed it from debug but did not work

Comment: I think about one only problem, try to use same firebase dependencies verisions. Maybe there is a conflict.