# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'. > Failed to create MD5 hash for file in Android Studio (Flutter)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle

I am using Android studio latest version, I added firebase dependencies in my project and also migrate it to AndriodX but still nonthing works.
Also tried invalidate cache/ Restart but its not works

**This is the Error which given after running my project**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
The system cannot find the path specified.
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\RIDER\AndroidStudioProjects\flash_chatgradleissue\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0\com\google\firebase\database\collection\R.dex' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**My pupspec.yml file**

```
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0<3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - images/
```

**My app/build.gradle file**

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}


def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

allprojects {

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.demon.flash_chat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My gradle/build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Flutter doctor report**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I am beginner in flutter development, I am suffering from 3 days in this issue tried many things but didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996612/error-apptransformclasseswithdexbuilderfordebug
Did your check this?

Comment: I tried this also now but it didn't work

Comment: an other way to fix this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Check that Path is defined in your system for AndroidStudio, it could be missing. If it is defined correctly then check for the permission of the AndroidStudio folder

Comment: I set the android sdk path also but still it not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: any other way to fix this issue